# Avro schema issue when record missing a field

Tags: avro, apache-nifi

I am using the NiFi (v1.2) processor ConvertJSONToAvro.  I am not able to parse a record that only contains 1 of 2 elements in a "record" type.  This element is also allowed to be missing entirely from the data.  Is my Avro schema incorrect?

Schema snippet:

```json
"name": "personname",
"type": [
  "null":,
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "firstandorlast",
    "fields": [
        {
          "name": "first",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "last",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

If "personname" contains both "first" and "last" it works, but if it only contains one of the elements, it fails with the error: Cannot convert field personname: cannot resolve union:

```json
{ "last":"Smith" }
```

not in

```json
"type": [ "null":, 
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "firstandorlast",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "first",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "last",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the default value

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_record

Your schema should looks like

```
"name": "personname",
"type": [
  "null":,
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "firstandorlast",
    "fields": [
        {
          "name": "first",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": "null"
        },
        {
          "name": "last",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": "null"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I add "default": "null" as suggested and that does allow the record to be parsed, however I am getting (lots of) warnings: Avro: Invalid default for field first (or last): "null" not a ["null","string"]

Comment: Changing "default": "null" to "default": null still gives the same warnings.

Comment: NEVERMIND, this was a "red herring", this schema is not the cause of the warning I am getting.  Yes, I feel dumb.